# What are the rules for coercing values to trait objects?

Tags: rust, traits, trait-objects

Consider the following Rust code:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
struct Struct;
trait Trait {}
impl Trait for Struct {}

fn f() {
    // Why does this coerce to the target type (Result<Box<dyn Trait>, ()>)
    let rbdt: Result<Box<dyn Trait>, ()> = Ok(Box::new(Struct));

    // And this coerces to the target type...
    let a = Box::new(Struct);
    let rbdt: Result<Box<dyn Trait>, ()> = Ok(a);

    // But this does not:
    let a = Ok(Box::new(Struct));
    let rbdt: Result<Box<dyn Trait>, ()> = a; // Error: mismatched types
}
```

Why do the first two assignments to `rbdt` work correctly, coercing the value into the target type (`Result<Box<dyn Trait>, ()>`), but the 3rd one does not? It seems to me that in all three cases the type of the RHS of the assignment is `Result<Box<Struct>, ()`>, so it's perplexing that some forms work while other cause a mismatched types error.

What are the rules governing when types containing trait objects can be assigned to? Are these documented anywhere?

Answer (score 4):

The underlying principle here is that the compiler will happily coerce a `Box<Struct>` into a `Box<dyn Trait>` by silently inserting an `as` wherever it's needed. But it needs a place to actually be able to rewrite the code as, literally, `boxed_struct as BoxedTrait`.

In the first example, this is possible:

```rust
let rbdt: Result<Box<dyn Trait>, ()> = Ok(Box::new(Struct) as Box<dyn Trait>);
```

And in the second:

```rust
let a = Box::new(Struct);
let rbdt: Result<Box<dyn Trait>, ()> = Ok(a as Box<dyn Trait>);
```

But in the third, there is nowhere for a `Box<Struct>`-as-`Box<Trait>` coercion to go. By the time you try to assign to `rbdt`, the type of `a` has already been determined to be `Result<Box<Struct>, ()>`, and at this point it's too late to try re-inferring the type to be the more general `Result<Box<Trait>, ()>`. The following is *not* a box-to-box coercion, so it isn't allowed.

```rust
let rbdt: Result<Box<dyn Trait>, ()> = a as Result<Box<dyn Trait>, ()>;
```

`Box<Struct>`-as-`Box<Trait>` is fine; `Type<Box<Struct>>`-as-`Type<Box<Trait>>`, for any `Type`, is not.

Comment: This answer is likely more technically correct, than mine, but I find the reasoning about inference to make more intuitive sense to me than thinking in terms of AST rewriting.

Comment: @IvanC I think both of our answers together make a solid answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is less about coercion, and more about inference.

In first two cases it can immediately be inferred that `T` in `Result<Box<T>>` is something other than `Struct`, while in the third `Box<Struct>` is already a concrete type which then conflicts with `T = dyn Trait` requirement introduced by type annotation on `rdbt`.

Additionally I want to note that it is generally not possible to coerce a value that already exists to a type of a different, especially larger, size, which `Box<Struct>` and `Box<dyn Trait>` are due to the latter being a fat pointer.